# How to skip or execute tasks/steps conditionally using TFS build?

Tags: variables, tfs, build, conditional-statements, task

I have a TFS build definition.

[image]

I wish to run two steps/task that execute two Command Lines, conditionally. Maybe with a variable I could set when I queue the build or something. Mainly I wish to run the build and skip some steps/task if I want to. How can I achieve this? Except making a bat file that executes my app.exe and sending a boolean variable to the bat script that will execute or not my app.exe.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Update 2017/04/19

You could [specify conditions for running a task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/process/conditions) in VSTS.

> To use this feature you must enable both the **New Build Editor** and **the
>   Task Conditions preview** features for your account.

---

For now, it's impossible. There has been a **feature request** in UserVoice and get  responded with **STARTED**:

> [Allow build vNext/preview tasks to be conditionally enabled or
>   disabled.](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/8623600-allow-build-vnext-preview-tasks-to-be-conditionall)
>
> We have begun to work on this feature and it will be available on both
>   team build and release management.
>
> *Team Services Group (Product group, Microsoft Visual Studio) responded  ·  August 23, 2016*

As a workaround,  you could manually disable the build task (Left click the build task and select ***Disable selected tasks*** ) as follow screenshot:
[image]

Comment: It is now possibile with https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/process/conditions

Comment: With TFS 2017 Update 2, the conditional execution of tasks is possible but not when they are part of task groups.

Comment: Up-to-date link to documentation (Azure DevOps = VSTS = TFS): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 4):

By adding a **PowerShell Script** task with `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ExecuteMyTask]$(ExecuteMyTask)"` before the task that needs to be executed conditionally, a new Process parameter named `ExecuteMyTask` is added to the Task Group that can be set to *true* or *false* (or left empty, to be set in the Build definition using this Task Group). In the 'conditional' task a *Custom Condition* `and(succeeded(), eq(variables['ExecuteMyTask'], 'true'))` can be added and the task will be executed conditionally.

This works on TFS.2018.2.